# SharePoint 2010 Wiki page columns

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, wiki

I created a wiki page library in sharepoint 2010 and i added several columns to the library. Is there any way to get these columns to show up on each wiki page as they did in SharePoint 2007